# Move TOP (x) records from one table to another with WHERE conditions

Tags: sql-server

I need to move the **TOP (X)** oldest rows from a live table into an ARCHIVE table, but the rows are not in date order.

Data will be moved on a DATE criteria and due to the fact that there are millions of records that may need to be moved over time, this will be done gradually.  Therefore the queries will use a **SELECT TOP** and **DELETE TOP**.

My SQL Script so far is

```
INSERT INTO tblDataLoggedArchived 
SELECT TOP(1000) *
FROM tblDataLogged
WHERE fldDateTime <= @ExpiryDate 
ORDER BY fldDateTime ASC

DELETE TOP(1000) FROM tblDataLogged
WHERE fldDateTime <= @ExpiryDate
***** ORDER BY fldDateTime ASC  **** HERE's the problem
COMMIT
```

However - here's the problem.

The records that are copied into the archive table have an ORDER BY clause applied to the SELECT. I need to make sure that these records are deleted from the original table - but you cannot specify an ORDER BY for the DELETE TOP query

I am by no means an SQL expert. Can someone please advise me the best way of moving the TOP X records from one table to another, using an ORDER BY parameter?

Note, the original table does not have any indexes.

Thanks

Comment: What's the PK on tblDataLoggedArchived?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can put into a CTE or derived table to delete the `TOP` ordered by some criteria.

Also there is no need for two statements here you can use the `OUTPUT` clause to do it all in one.

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT TOP(1000) *
         FROM   tblDataLogged
         WHERE  fldDateTime <= @ExpiryDate
         ORDER  BY fldDateTime ASC)
DELETE FROM T
OUTPUT DELETED.*
INTO tblDataLoggedArchived
```

Comment: Thanks - that this fantastic. Would never have thought to have done it that way.

Answer (score 2):

Although I think @MartinSmith has the superior solution I figure I'll throw in an alternative as well.

Start of with your standard insert statement as you had it.

```
INSERT INTO tblDataLoggedArchived 
SELECT TOP(1000) *
FROM tblDataLogged
WHERE fldDateTime <= @ExpiryDate 
ORDER BY fldDateTime ASC
```

Then join back to your main table to do the delete operation.

```
DELETE L
FROM tblDataLogged as L
INNER JOIN tblDataLoggedArchived as A
    ON L.KeyValue = A.KeyValueDELETE L
```

You may wish to refine the delete criteria to give a better execution play but this is just an example.

Keep in mind that I feel Martins Solution is superior just offering another method.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution.